# Can I use a wildcard in a SQL window function?

Tags: sql, window-functions

Say I have a table of invoice transactions and one of the fields is invoice_number. Each invoice number needs to be unique for its vendor, so vendor A can have invoice numbers ABC001 and ABC002 and vendor B can also have invoice numbers ABC001 and ABC002. Included in this table are erroneous invoice transactions that have some kind of suffix appended to the end of the invoice number. It could be ABC001-1 or ABC001/1 or ABC001A or any other possible permutation. Here's my question: can I use a window function to identify the "real" invoices that have these suffix'd transactions? I'm envisioning some kind of wildcard in the PARTITION BY clause, but I can't figure out how that'd work:

```
SELECT
...
,COUNT(invoice_number) OVER (PARTITION BY 'invoice_number%') AS count

FROM invoices_table
```

In my brain, the end result would look something like this, where the invoices with counts greater than 1 are the ones that have the additional rows with the suffixes:

| vendor | invoice_number | count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | ABC001 | 2 |
| A | ABC001-1 | 1 |
| A | ABC002 | 1 |
| A | ABC003 | 2 |
| A | ABC003A | 1 |
| B | DEF001 | 1 |
| B | DEF002 | 1 |

Edit: I added a second vendor to the example table and I'm working in Oracle EBS.

Comment: not so as you want it, but please add create table and data and wanted result (idealey for more than one vendor, in this form it os hard to guess, also state your database system

Comment: If your invoice numbers are always 6 characters long and suffix is beyond those 6 characters, then calculate a relevant substring and group by it `PARTITION BY (LEFT(invoice_number, 6))`

Comment: Thanks for this note, but they're not unfortunately. The invoice numbers can be anything. One could be 1. Another could be XFEPSJ3344411-1-1. Another could be INVOICE01. The trick is that the erroneous ones always have the full, original invoice number plus something appended to the end. So INVOICE01 could have another row with INVOICE01-A, for example.

Comment: As you explained the task so far, it is not possible to solve, if the length of correct invoice numbers could be different even for the same vendor. If the length or leading pattern (e.g. digits only) would be identical for all invoices of one vendor however, you could identify this length (or pattern) first (e.g. the shortest per vendor) and then show all the ones which are different